# How to fetch a html page(elements) with JS

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch a content of a page. When I inspect and go under the 'Elements' section, I can see the needed data in span tag for example, but when I try to fetch which I do as a get request to the url, I receive different HTML that doesn't contain the same data but less.

This is how I try to fetch my data

```js
async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(response.data)
}
```

What would be the reason of the difference and how could I solve it?

Should I use different technique?

Comment: If I were to *guess*, maybe the website you're looking at has some JavaScript code to update page content.  Web scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering, so you're going to need to dig into where the data you want comes from and how to find it.  (Which is why using an API to get data is vastly preferred where possible.)  If this is the case then another potential option for reverse-engineering is to use a "headless browser" to render the target page in code, then parse out the data you want.

Comment: Are you able to see the span tag when you view source?  The get would grab only the page source content and not the content which dynamically gets built on the client side.. that’s why you are getting lesser data…. What happens if you wrap the get function in a settimeout function?

Comment: @David Well yeah there is no API so I was aiming to get the data directly from public website. I am going to check headless browser but while I was searching more, I found out something like Web Scraper tool Scraper. Do you think it can solve my problem?

Comment: @sydadder Yes I can view and I tried settimeout but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed, crawlers are supposed to use parsing tools, like Puppeteer library or Cheerio for data-grabbing.

Here are some references:

[github puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

[npm puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)

I've tried to do something like that a few times ago.
If you're having troubles - ask for help